# How to read this input? Trying to use sys.stdin.readline()

Tags: python, stdin, sys

Trying to use this code to read an input for an exercise but not working

```
import sys

def get_string():
   return sys.stdin.readlines()

inputs = get_string()
print(type(inputs))
```

The input is in this link:

https://pastebin.com/M5s9Svw8

when I execute this code the text seems to be corrupted in my terminal appears this text. One line in the middle seems different from the original.

https://pastebin.com/fb08qw4C

and it doesn't print the type of the file...

Comment: What you mean in `type of the file` and is built-in `open` not an option to be used?

Comment: in the code above there is a line print(type(inputs)). The code doesn't go there... actually no...its an exercise in one of those sites that tests codes and the inputs its like the way that is the pastbin link

Comment: Code does not go there, because `sys.stdin.readlines()` needs some kind of signal (EOF) to stop reading. If this signal is not sent, it just waits new input from `stdin`.